# Is there EAV model like systems implemented in NoSQL?

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value, nosql

I'm in the midst of implementing a database that would contain dynamic attributes in a table. Something similar to Magento e-commerce site. As we know that Magento follows EAV model with MySQL and very flexible to customize.
Is there open source systems implemented based on EAV modeling with NoSQL databases. Curious to know the best practices of applying EAV model with NoSQL databases. or is there any other ways to implementing in NoSQL.

Comment: [Copernic](https://github.com/amirouche/copernic/) does that plus adds versioning